# Remove html part with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this code (part of an ajax request) that generate a label with an error when i press submit button in a form and some validation conditions are not obtained

```
error: function (err) {
            if (err.status == 422) { // when status code is 422, it's a validation issue
                $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
                console.log(err.responseJSON);
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(err.responseJSON.message);
                // you can loop through the errors object and show it to the user
                console.warn(err.responseJSON.errors);
                // display errors on each form field
                $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
                    var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');
                    el.next().remove();
                    el.after($('<span style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));
                });
            }
        }
```

But when i correct error according to validation, error label remain, how can i delete it? Should i loop with some code throught every form element?
Thx

Comment: add html code as well

Comment: something like this             $('#updateAnaFrm *').filter(':input').each(function(){
                //here code remove but i dunno which to remove 
            });

Comment: add a specific identifier to them, then on success select them all and remove them

Comment: but i want to remove only if the span error appears to a specific element of the form